# Any inbuilt function to convert ip/prefix to list of ip address

Tags: c, ip

I want to generate the list of IP address from ip/prefix input.

I am trying to find a function or any pointers that can help me to achieve that.

Basically, what I am trying is to write a port scanner which will scan all IP given ip/prefix.

If such function does not exists, could please give me any pointers on how to make one.

--Amey

Comment: [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) is a great port scanner and it can scan ranges as well.